# Select all properties of a cmis type

Tags: opencmis

I'd like to list all properties attached to a cmis object such as `cmis:document`. The idea is to return properties name, id, description just like it is done in opencmis-workbench

[image]

Any idea I could get the same result?

UPDATE:
Thanks to @Florian Müller, I found a solution:

```
String myType = "cmis:document";
ObjectType type = session.getTypeDefinition(myType);
Map<String, PropertyDefinition<?>> propertyDefinitions = type.getPropertyDefinitions();
propertyDefinitions.each { name, value ->
    println "name = ${name}, value = ${value.getDisplayName()}"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code sample:

```
Document doc = ...
ObjectType type = doc.getType();

for(String propId: type.getPropertyDefinitions().keySet()) {
    System.out.println(propId + ": " + doc.getPropertyValue(propId));
}
```

It only covers the primary type. If you want all properties, you have to iterate over secondary types as well.

Comment: Yes, but that's not SQL-92

Comment: There is no SQL-92 in CMIS. There is CMIS QL, which I very similar but not the same. You cannot get the type definitions via CMIS QL.

Comment: Looks like there is SQL-92 in CMIS https://docs.oasis-open.org/cmis/CMIS/v1.1/errata01/csd01/CMIS-v1.1-errata01-csd01-complete.html

Comment: No, there is not. Believe me, I'm the CMIS specification editor.